# Can't tell the difference between "similar" code

Tags: javascript

I have a nested function that re-writes a variable in the parent function. I tried two different invocation syntaxes. Both legal, yet the second one gives undesirable results.

I know scope is determined during definition, but that doesn't seem to help, since both snippets of code seem the same to me.

```
var countUpFromZero = function() {
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
        return ++count;
    };
}();
countUpFromZero(); // Desirable result
```

```
var countUpFromZero = function() {
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
        return ++count;
    };
};
countUpFromZero()(); //Undesirable result
```

Comment: Both are the same. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Welcome.  Please read [ask], especially how to create an [mcve].  A clear problem statement includes the input and the desired output.

Comment: `console.log(countUpFromZero)` will show that you have two very different things. In the first case you have one counter. In the second, you're creating a new counter every time.

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't say, but I'm assuming the problem is what happens when you call the function *more than once*. The issue is very simple. Let's change things just a tiny bit, by defining this:

```
var make_a_counter = function() {
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
        return ++count;
    };
};
```

Now, let's add a variable to your first example:

```
var counter = make_a_counter();
counter(); // returns 1
counter(); // returns 2
```

Simple, right? Your second example is equivalent to this:

```
make_a_counter()(); // returns 1
make_a_counter()(); // returns 1, because you made a *new* counter!
```

Except in your first example, as provided, you never give `make_a_counter` a name, you call it with `()` at the same time as it's defined, so you only *can* ever make one counter. If you delay calling it, you can make as many of them as you want, and control exactly how long they last.